# Azure DevOps SSH Task failing in inline script option

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, recently SSH task is failing when I ran SSH task as a inline script.
Earlier I was running this command in SSH task as inline script and deployment was successful before.

```sh
cd /www/xxx/xxx/xxx/platform
source setantenv_devops.sh
ant updatesystem -Dtenant=xxx -DconfigFile=/www/xxx/xxx/xxx/platform/xxx_update_config.json
```

Now since this issue of not able to run azure devops ssh task as inline script i want to run the SSH task as commands option in azure DevOps but it's failing with error

> ##[error]bash: setantenv_devops.sh: No such file or directory

But the file setantenv_devops.sh exists in that particular location.

Comment: Can you list files before calling `source setantenv_devops.sh`?

Comment: after the first step i was able to do 'ls' and list all files in there

Comment: Ok. Can you show use what files you have there?

Comment: thank you i found that what i was missing and changed multiple lines to single command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure DevOps SSH task in commands option executes the command cd /www/xxx/xxx/xxx/platform and then goes back to user working directory. so I tried with below option and multiple lines of command as a single command and it worked.
Thanks @Krzysztof Madej

```
cd /www/xxx/xxx/xxx/platform && source setantenv_devops.sh && ant updatesystem -Dtenant=xxx -DconfigFile=/www/xxx/xxx/xxx/platform/xxx_update_config.json
```